# Node.js + Socket.io: Detect client-side when user has disconnected due to inactivity

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to detect client-side when a user has disconnected **due to INACTIVITY**. For me, using a disconnect() event doesn't work because it encompasses other forms of a client disconnecting besides inactivity.

My current code:

```
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("You have been disconnected from the match.");
});
```

Comment: As an spontaneous idea: use a `setTimeout` and restart it every time the user does something on your page / app. If the timeout finally fires, the user is inactive and gets disconnected duo inactivity.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you!

```js
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    //it emits a logoff event
    socket.emit("logoff", { reason: "Disconnected due to inactivity" });
    console.log("You have been disconnected from the match.");
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I only would like an event to be triggered when the client disconnects specifically due to inactivity and only inactivity,

Answer (score 0):

On your server side:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected'); // client has been disconnected, client maybe has many connections.
  });
});
```

Orther way, Client side takes a http request to noti to server that it has been disconnected.

```
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("You have been disconnected from the match.");
    $.post('http://serverdomain/socket/' + socket.id + '/disconnected') // Just make a http request,
    // example by jQuery
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I only would like an event to be triggered when the client disconnects specifically due to inactivity and only inactivity.